# Error While Generating PDF using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am Creating a PDF using ItextSharp 5.0.5

Used follwing Code

1)

```
var _with1 = underContent;
_with1.SaveState();
_with1.SetGState(gstate);
_with1.SetColorFill(color);
_with1.BeginText();
_with1.SetFontAndSize(font, txt_Font2);
_with1.SetTextMatrix(30, 30);

//**1**//

_with1.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, watermarkText, txt_X2, txt_Y2, txt_Rotat2);

//**1**//

_with1.EndText();
_with1.RestoreState();
```

2)

```
//**2**//

ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(_with1, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(new Chunk(watermarkText, FontFactory.GetFont(@"C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\" + FntNm + ".TTF", txt_Font2, 0))), txt_X2, txt_Y2, txt_Rotat2);

//**2**//
```

Replacing `//**1**//` with `//**2**//` i am getting Following Error

[image: ERROR]

i need to use //**2**// for generating UNDERLINE which is not supported in BaseFont of iTextsharp

Please Help!!

Comment: FWIW - there is no underlined text in PDF.  Underlines are made by drawing an actual line.

Comment: `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned` calls `SaveState,` `BeginText` etc. itself. Thus, don't start a text object yourself when using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting text objects! That's illegal. More recent iTextSharp versions warn you about this problem.

Bottom line: you need to remove at least the following lines:

```
_with1.BeginText();
_with1.SetFontAndSize(font, txt_Font2);
_with1.SetTextMatrix(30, 30);
_with1.EndText();
```

The whole idea of using the `ColumnText` method is that you don't have to worry about creating the text object yourself (as explained in Chapter 3 of my book).